# Override @ngrx/data, @ngrx/entity Actions, Reducer, Effects

Tags: ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

I'm new to *@ngrx/data* and trying to understand how I can override the *reducer* & *actions*.

My current *problem* could be solved in other ways like adding an extra method, reducer & action but I  would probably need this answer in the future.

The problem is that my delete call should just set the item to "hidden" in the store and not to delete it.

This is the set-up I'm using: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-data-tutorial